# Tabela zebrada atualizável

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Fiz uma tabela em html com 5 colunas e mais de 300 linhas. Nessa tabela eu coloquei um `<th>` com duas linhas, onde na primeira eu tenho os títulos de cada coluna e na segunda um campo para pesquisas na tabela. Conforme a pessoa vai digitando a tabela vai sendo atualizada com os resultados obtidos. o código que utilizei foi esse:

```
$(function(){
    $("#tabela input").keyup(function(){        
        var index = $(this).parent().index();
        var nth = "#tabela td:nth-child("+(index+1).toString()+")";
        var valor = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
        $("#tabela tbody tr").show();
        $(nth).each(function(){
            if($(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(valor) < 0){
                $(this).parent().hide();
            }
        });
    });
 
    $("#tabela input").blur(function(){
        $(this).val("");
    }); 
});
```

Essa tabela eu deixei sem bordas e pra não ficar muito simples eu resolvi deixar ela zebrada, porém ao realizar as consultas esse zebrado desaparece. Por exemplo, se a minha pesquisa retorna 20 resultados, ao invés de 10 colunas com cor e 10 sem cor intercaladas, aparecem várias linhas com cor juntas deixando um bloco cinza no meio da tabela.

Eu estava usando o CSS pra fazer o zebrado e não consegui fazer ele atualizar com a consulta nem usando reza. Nas minhas pesquisas pela internet achei algumas coisas e tentei implementar mas nada deu certo, agora estou usando o próprio javascript para fazer o zebrado usando esse código:

```
$(function(){

  $("tr:nth-child(odd)").css("background-color", "#DCDCDC");
  $("tr:nth-child(odd)").css("color", "black");
  $("tr:nth-child(odd)").css("font-weight", "bold");

});
```

Em suma eu só quero que ao realizar a pesquisa a tabela continue zebrada. É possível fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com o que entendi, a solução é encapsular em uma função essa parte que faz o "zebramento".

```
function zebrar(){ 
   $("tr:nth-child(odd)").css("background-color", "#DCDCDC");
   $("tr:nth-child(odd)").css("color", "black");
   $("tr:nth-child(odd)").css("font-weight", "bold");
}
```

E chame a função `zebrar()` após seu evento de atualização da tabela. E também chamar essa função no primeiro carregamento da tabela.

Espero ter ajudado, caso não seja esse seu problema detalhe melhor por favor.

Comment: eu tentei fazer dessa forma e não deu muito certo. O problema continua aparecendo vou postar como ficou o código alterado pois posso estar cometendo algum erro na chamada da função. Não conheço muito bem js, olhei a documentação na web mas ainda não consegui identificar o posso estar fazendo de errado.

Answer (score 0):

Esse é o código já alterado:

```
/* Função para pesquisa na tabela de pool*/
$(function(){
    $("#tabela input").keyup(function(){        
        var index = $(this).parent().index();
        var nth = "#tabela td:nth-child("+(index+1).toString()+")";
        var valor = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
        zebrar();
        $("#tabela tbody tr").show();
        $(nth).each(function(){
            if($(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(valor) < 0){
                $(this).parent().hide();
            }
        });
    });
    $("#tabela input").blur(function(){
        $(this).val("");
    }); 
});


/*cria a tabela zebrada e aplica os estilos*/
function zebrar(){ 
   $("tr:nth-child(odd)").css("background-color", "#DCDCDC");
   $("tr:nth-child(odd)").css("color", "black");
   $("tr:nth-child(odd)").css("font-weight", "bold");
}
```

No html eu apenas inclui na tag `<body>` o atributo `onload="zebrar()"`

Comment: Meu caro até onde teste aqui o CSS faz isso perfeitamente `tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #f5f5f5}` faz mais uma tentaiva. Não há necessidade ao meu ver de usar JS.

Comment: Eu realizei outros testes aqui e mesmo assim não funciona. Eu estava utilizando o css já, mas não funcionava do jeito esperado, então pesquisando pela internet vi que era possível aterar o estilo utilizando o javascript, por isso mudei pra ele na tentativa de fazer os dois scripts conversarem, mas sem sucesso ainda.

Comment: @fweydson realizei mais alguns testes e descobri que tanto o css quanto o javascript estavam funcionando normalmente, entretanto acredito que tenha algo "errado" na pesquisa. Pelo que pude perceber  quando o trecho do código que esconde as linhas sem correspondência é executado, as linhas escondidas ainda são computadas pelo css como sendo parte da tabela e por isso o zebrado fica desconfigurado. Talvez se eu conseguir alterar a forma como o filtro ocorre ou se eu conseguir fazer o js desconsiderar essas linhas a tabela continue com o aspecto zebrado.

Comment: Eu inclusive já tentei trocar o `parent().hide()` por `parent().remove()` mas não surtiu o efeito esperado e também não acho viável, pq se o usuário precisar realizar outra pesquisa vai precisar fazer um refresh na página pra recarregar a tabela inteira.